# dir-pagination-controls only showing first 10 items. Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<tr dir-paginate="plan in access |itemsPerPage: 10" total-items="planCount" current-page="current">
      <td>{{plan._id}}</td>
      <td>{{plan.name}}</td>
      <td>{{plan.email}}</td>
      <td>{{plan.contactNumber}}</td>
      <td>{{plan.accessToken}}</td>
      <td>{{plan.downloadSpeed | toMBPS}}</td>
      <td>{{plan.uploadSpeed | toMBPS}}</td>
      <td>{{plan.issueTime}}</td>
```

and this is the directive

```
<div class="text-center">
  <dir-pagination-controls auto-hide="false" on-page-change="pageChanged(newPageNumber)"></dir-pagination-controls>
</div>
```

and this is the angular code

```
$scope.planCount = 0;
  $scope.current = 1;
  $scope.pageChanged = function(value) {
    console.log("Going to page" + value);
  }
```

The data is coming from the server, but that is working fine. I have logged the data, and I am receiving the complete data. Also, it is the registering the changed page number correctly.

Still, it only shows the first ten items, doesn't matter on what page number I am.

Note: Don't mind the incomplete html. That is the only relevant part to my situation. I can't post the whole code.

Also, I am using this in a different page, but it's working fine in it.

Comment: What you got on the console log?

Comment: There are chances you might be getting same first 10 result from the server side.It will be clear if u show what is your response from server side.Do you get every time next changed records on changing the page number.

Comment: @N.K I've fixed it. The server side was missing pagination.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr dir-paginate="plan in access |itemsPerPage: 10" total-items="planCount" current-page="current">
```

From above line remove `total-items="planCount"`. It'll work here too.